# Security Error - Bug Shooting return Data has been tampered error in Success page?

Tags: security, payment-gateway, bug, magento1.9.2.3, core-hacks

Magento 1.9 - Using Bug Shooting if i try to place an order i am getting response regard **Data has been tampered**. How to solve this security issue?

[image]

Comment: you need to read error log, we dont know how exactly this payment gateway was integrated. probably request/response do not match or hash is lost.

Comment: there is only developer working directly with your code can help you. or ask help from payment gateway provider.

Comment: @zus do you use https when make a request?

Comment: Yes, my site have ssl certificate.

Comment: is there any observer who update price? Also can you please let me know which payment method are you using to place an order.

Comment: Payubiz payment gateway

Comment: No, there is no observer to update price.

Comment: share the URL of the extension, which you use?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya HDFC technical team share the package, https://github.com/ZusZus/Payubiz